# show dialog before asynctask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm trying to show a "Loading" dialog before the async task starts working. With the following code what happens is that the dialog doesn't show untill all the async task is done his operations, the dialog is being prompted only in the end.

Here's the code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    loadMap();
    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Map.this, "", 
            "Loading. Please wait...", true);

    //firing the asynctask here
}
```

The asynctask is doing pretty heavy operation, it takes like 10 seconds till I'm able to see the layout, that's why I want to prompt the user with a "Loading" dialog. but the user is able to see it only in the end of the asynctask operations for some reason.

What should I do?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that in the onProgressUpdate I'm doing some UI operations (Adding the overlays to the mapview). That's why the UI is freezing probably. but I just want to know how to show the loading dialog before, I don't care if the UI freezes after the "loading" dialog shows. Actually I do care, but I don't know if there's any better solution.

**EDIT2:** The loadmap function:

```
    public void loadMap()
{

        mapView = (TapControlledMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)(47.975 * 1E6), (int)(17.056 * 1E6)));
        mapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {      
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                itemizedOverlay.hideAllBalloons();
                return true;
            }
        });
        myLocationOverlay = new FixedMyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
        mapView.invalidate();
        zoomToMyLocation();

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus)
                onSearchRequested();
                EditText editText = (EditText)v;
                editText.clearFocus();

            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Show the progress bar in the `onPreExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask` and dismiss it in the `onPostExecute()` method

Comment: @SiddharthLele I've already tried it, I have no idea why the UI is freezing.. even though all the operations are on the asynctask thread.

Comment: I'll repeat myself: if it matters, the operations in the asynctask are heavy and takes around 10 seconds to finish.

Comment: @SiddharthLele Just setting up the map(on the UI thread), nothing special in there. I forgot to mention something very important. I'll mention is now.

Comment: @SiddharthLele Please have a look in my edit.

Comment: @idish: try commenting out the maps method temporarily and see what happens....

Comment: @SiddharthLele Added the loadmap() to my post ^, commenting the method crashing the app.

Comment: I'm away from my computer so can't troubleshoot. Anyway, did you comment out any dependencies too? And also, what are you extending for this java file?

Comment: Something very weird happens, even though the onCreate is the following: http://pastebin.com/3mEDfRCi the app crashes.

Comment: Also, I tried to make the asynctask thread sleep in the dobackground[] method, but the UI still freezes for some reason.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/qUNK9qUS

Comment: @androiddeveloper As I said.. pretty long. Have any suggestions? I'm really getting tired of this issue.

Comment: are there any other asyncTasks running ? i ask this because starting of a specific android version (honeycomb) , only a single thread is used for all of the asyncTasks .

Comment: No, it is the only async task running, and I'm using API 8 anyways.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Ah, have any idea for me? The UI freezes because I always invoke the main thread from the asynctask to add the overlays to the mapview.

Comment: @SiddharthLele You too maybe?

Comment: @idish : i don't understand . if you use only a single asyncTask and do the long operations in the doInBackground and not wait for it in the main thread , the UI should be fine . where do you create&call the PostTask ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'll just show you the whole code http://pastebin.com/BAYqTRSW

Comment: @androiddeveloper As you can see I create the postTask in the loadsettings() function.

Comment: @androiddeveloper BTW, if it matters, my app has tabs, so once I create press on the "Map" tab, the UI freezes, and I'm able it switches to the Map tab only after the postTask finish his operations.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried moving `loadMap()` in to the asynctask ?

Comment: How can I do it? the loadmap() is messing with UI objects.